# in_groups_of not displaying as rows

Tags: html, css

I have a rails blog that I am trying to display my posts in 3 different columns on. When using in_groups_of I am able to make the logic work by replacing @posts with a sample array like [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] and it will display the numbers in three items per row, but when I use my posts (which contain images - I don't know if that matters), it displays them one per row. Any ideas for how to solve this?

```
<div class='posts'>
    <% @posts.in_groups_of(3, false).each do |group| %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="three columns">
          <% group.each do |post| %>
            <div class='titleTxt'>
                        <%= link_to post.title, post_path(post.id) if post %>
                    </div>
                    <div class='bodyTxt'>
                        <%= raw post.body if post %>
                    </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: also, I don't think it's a CSS formatting thing concerning the posts because I have been tweaking that to see if it was the issue

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code, are you sure `@posts` actually contains something? You can do `<%= @posts.inspect %>` at the top to see what it holds.

Comment: All of the posts are displaying the correct content (I think that's what your question is), it's just not formatting it in grouped rows/columns like it should.

Comment: That's more of an html/css issue than a rails one then, are you using any html framework?

Comment: The images are part of the post body -- using tinyMCE to create each post

Comment: I mean, are you using some html/css framework like bootstrap or foundation or your own css?

Comment: Nope, just my own CSS, which I've stripped down to see if I had some width/sizing thing that was throwing it off, but hasn't seemed to change anything.